# Can I switch from 64bit to 32bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Is their anyway I can switch from Ubuntu 64-bit to Ubuntu 32-bit easily without replacing the whole OS.

Answer (score 10):

No, I don't think so. You will have to reinstall the entire OS (the root partition, to be precise.). The packages and the kernel will have to switch back to the 32-bit version. At the most, you can keep the same home directory, so you don't lose your settings, bookmarks, Music, Photos, etc.

Comment: And before reinstall you can save your installed package marks from Synaptic (File - Save marks), and install them all in new system.

Comment: @Extender: **Except** that some packages have no equivalent 32-bit version - like `ia32-libs`.