# How to change Ubuntu from 64 to 32 bit

Tags: updates, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I switch from ubuntu amd64 to ubuntu 32bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39243/can-i-switch-from-ubuntu-amd64-to-ubuntu-32bit)

My brother installed 64 bit Ubuntu on my moms old PC (dualboot with winXP) and it runs very crappily. It is on Ubuntu 11.10 and I was wondering if there is any easy way of updating to 32 bit 12.04. I know on fedora when you insert instillation media on a computer that already has fedora it asks you if you want to install it over that fedora, is there anything like this for Ubuntu. THANKS!