# How to change Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit to 32 bit without loosing data or changing settings

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

i accidentally  installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on my 32 bit Pc and already installed a lot of important things. How can I change it to 32 bit OS without loosing data or settings?

Comment: if it works, then you have a 64-bit compatible pc. What kind of CPU do you have? that's what matters.

Comment: One oword: **backup**!!!!

Comment: As **@akvar** noted: Why do even need/want 32-bit? Are you limited to <1GB RAM? *You do know **64-bit** OS still runs **32-bit** software.*

Comment: As **@d4av1dsix** says everything will still work.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39243/can-i-switch-from-ubuntu-amd64-to-ubuntu-32bit

Answer (score 0):

You can not run 64 bit os on a 32 bit processor, so if you are successfully running it, then your cpu must be 64 bit